# Android PDFDocument is producing a blank document

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf-generation

I'm using Android Studio and trying to get my app to produce a PDF. I've set up an Activity which generates the content that I want my PDF to have. This works fine if I let it display on screen.  The onCreate part of the Activity is below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Connect to database
    connectToDatabase();

    // Set view
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_export_pattern);

    // find various views and set up their contents 
    // (I've left this bit out as it's quite long, but it doesn't contain 
    // anything controversial)

    // Now try to export to PDF.  
    // Return success or failure to calling activity 
    //  (basically just displays a toast indicating success/failure)
    try {
        if(exportToPDF()) {
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
        }else {
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
            finish();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

If I omit the final part (the try-catch), and just let it display on the screen, it works fine.  The screen displays what I expect it to display.

However, to get it to create a PDF, I use the try-catch with the call to exportToPDF, which contains the following code (this is basically the code from the Android documentation, with a few changes as indicated by comments below):

```
   public boolean exportToPDF() {
        // Create PDF document
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        // Create page description
        // Line below changed as Android Studio was highlighting an error; 
        //  instead of Rect, I have just put numbers.
        //  I've varied the numbers from 100 up to 1000, to no effect
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(720, 720, 1).create();
        // Start page
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
        // Changed the line below from content = getContentView, as that was causing an error
        // pageContent is the id of the overall LinearLayout in the XML file
        // If I break after this in the debugger, content seems to have found the correct view and be populated with the appropriate page elements
        View content =  this.findViewById(R.id.pageContent);
        // Added the line below after finding it suggested on here in another question
        //  Doesn't seem to make any difference
        content.layout(0, 0, 200, 200);
        if (content != null) {
            content.draw(page.getCanvas());
        }
        // Finish page
        document.finishPage(page);

        // Write document content to external storage
        // I'm using a FileOutputStream instead of BufferedOutputStream as given in the documentation, but, since this does at least produce a file, I don't think this is the source of the problem
        String filename = this.item.getName() + ".pdf";
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/" + filename);
        FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
        try {
            fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            document.writeTo(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
            document.close();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(fileOut != null) fileOut.close();
            document.close();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

So, running this produces a PDF in the correct directory, named correctly, but it's blank.  I've no idea what else to try.

Comment: check your content view width and hieght

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you writing view to PDF  onCreate() in activity, it won't work and because your view returned 0 height and width. You need to wait for activity window to attached and then write view to pdf. You can try calling exportToPDF from onWindowFocusChanged() method of your activity.

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
try {
        if(exportToPDF()) {
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
        }else {
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
            finish();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }

    }
```

You can also use ViewTreeObserver

```
 View content =  this.findViewById(R.id.pageContent);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = content.getViewTreeObserver(); 
            vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
                @Override 
                public void onGlobalLayout() { 
              try {
            if(exportToPDF()) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }else {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
            finish();
        }
content.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    } 
            });
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll give that a go.

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I didn't need to use the second part (viewTreeObserver). Just need to fiddle with the page and content sizes now. Thanks again for your help.